# typescript how to use setInterval inside a service worker

Tags: javascript, typescript, service-worker

I'm developing a PWA (at least a little bit), and I need that at certain intervals the app queries the remote database and updates its information, as well as sending the locally saved data.
But when trying to use the `setInterval()` within the `Service Worker`, it doesn't work.
I need it to run this update even in the background, how can I do that?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Please provide a [mre].